# Having some trouble with my exactlyOneOdd function

Tags: python

provided instructions are:
Define a function `exactlyOneOdd()` with the following contract:

**inputs**: `two integers, a and b`

**output**: `boolean`

**behavior**: returns `True` if exactly one of the parameters is odd.  Returns `False` if neither parameter is odd, or if both are odd.

Code:

```
def exactlyOneOdd(a, b):
    if a or b % 2 == 1:
      odd = False
      return False
    elif a or b % 2 == 1:
      odd = True
      return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of two even numbers is even. The sum of two odd numbers is also even. The sum of an odd and even number is odd though. So, you can just check the sum against 2 with the modulo operator.

```
def exactlyOneOdd(a,b):
    return True if (a+b)%2!=0 else False
```

As was pointed out by @Boris, you don't need the if statement. You could simply do

```
def exactlyOneOdd(a,b):
    return (a+b)%2!=0
```

something like this should work. I would encourage you to look into number theory a bit. This sounds very much like a homework problem and if you truly want to learn then struggle through the learning. There are example proofs out there that will verify my first set of statements e.g. https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-that-the-sum-of-any-two-odd-integers-is-even. You can even derive these yourself if you are so interested. Odd integers can be represented as 2k+1 and even integers as 2k. So you can clearly get to odd or even results adding up these values for your respective cases.

Comment: you don't need to do `return True if <whatever> else False` you can just do `return <whatever>`. In some instances you'll have to do `return bool(<whatever>)` but not in this one.

Comment: Agreed. I think it adds clarity though for a newer user.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is the following.
`a or b % 2 == 1` is equal to `a or (b%2 == 1)`
meaning, unless `a` is zero the it will be evaluated to `True`
Always use `()` when in doubt.
Also, you have same condition on both `if` and `elif` block.
Lastly, you are not using the local variable `odd`, which is not needed anyway.
Following will do the trick:

```
def exactlyOneOdd(a, b):
    # check if both are odd OR both are even
    if ((a%2==0) and (b%2==0)) or ((a%2==1) and (b%2==1)):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Another easy solution is, as @sokato mentioned, using the fact that
the sum of two even or two odd integers is even and odd otherwise.

```
def exactlyOneOdd(a, b):
    return (a+b)%2 == 1
```